# How can you get the price of token on Uniswap using solidity?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I'm trying to create a function that takes a token address as the parameter and returns the price of the token.  I saw another post that mentioned the Uniswap SDK, but that used javascript.  I'm wondering is there anyway to get the token price using solidity?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with uniswap if you know the pair address. You will need to import [IUniswapV2Pair.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol).

You would also need import [ERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) but better to use an interface like [IERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol) or you can make your own interface but it will need this:

```
/**
 * @dev Returns the decimals.
 */
function decimals() external view returns (uint256);
```

And the solidity function:

```
   // calculate price based on pair reserves
   function getTokenPrice(address pairAddress, uint amount) public view returns(uint)
   {
    IUniswapV2Pair pair = IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress);
    IERC20 token1 = IERC20(pair.token1);
    (uint Res0, uint Res1,) = pair.getReserves();

    // decimals
    uint res0 = Res0*(10**token1.decimals());
    return((amount*res0)/Res1); // return amount of token0 needed to buy token1
   }
```

Comment: To improve precision, multiply before dividing. `return (amount * res0) / res1;`

Comment: Hah I was still editing my answer when you commented. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You'll get an explicit type conversion error with the above as `pair.token1` should be `pair.token1()`. Otherwise it worked great though!

Comment: @Stakedex.io Why did you multiple it with token1.decimals() when the returned values are already in wei?